# Is there a known algorithm to find path to any direction but with limited direction?

Tags: algorithm

[image: The algorithm visualized]

I made this algorithm because I can't find it anywhere, and as a learning opportunity.
Is there a name for it?

The gray line is the distance and angle we wanted. The colored line is the angle we only have to work with. The dotted line is maximum distance the algorithm allowed to offset from.

This algorithm also works with only up/down/left/right.

[Source code repository](https://github.com/Multirious/limited-direction). (It's in Rust)

Comment: What does it solve? Because it looks like its trying "a lot" of possibilities before it finds out the correct path.

Comment: @libik Every frame of the animation shows a different goal point (on a circle around the start point) and shows the path to it. We don't see any "trying". It only shows results.

Comment: @KellyBundy - well then it is not alghoritm that actually solves anything, right? It is just simple procedure that start the line in some direction and then bounce once it hits the wall. If so, its just part of the game logic of arkanoid or even older Pong game.

Comment: @libik An algorithm doesn't need to be a *complicated* procedure. Yes, looks like they mostly bounce off the walls.

Comment: @KellyBundy - well the point was not about the complexity, but it is not "solving" anything.  i.e. backtracking itself is few lines of code, but it solves some tasks. As I do not see anything that this actually solves + the alghoritm of bouncing seems pretty straightforward usage of simple math, I am assuming this alghoritm does not have any special name.

Comment: @KellyBundy - cool visualisation fo that alghoritm though :)

Comment: @libik It does solve the task they described ...